# flink ReducingState impact performance

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

found out when we used ReducingState RecordStore.add(r), the performance is fluctuated as shown,

without ReducingState:
[stable performance graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaFrj.png)

with ReducingState:
[fluctuated performance graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxYyu.png)

Overall performance(drop more than 100%!):
[without Reducingstate.add VS with ReducingState.add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jAOQ.png)

It could be easyly reproduce with a simple app, without checkpoint, just simply keep storing record, also with simple 'sum' reduction function(in fact with empty function would see the same result). Any idea would be appreciated. What an unbelievable obvious issue.

Basically the app just keep storing record into the state, and we measure how many record per second in "JsonTranslator", which is shown in the graph. The difference between is just 1 line, comment/un-comment "recStore.add(r)".

Understand state will impact performance, but is this the way it works?

```
DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(new GeneratorSource(loop);
DataStream<JSONObject> convert = stream.map(new JsonTranslator(statsdUrl))
                                       .keyBy(new KeySelector<JSONObject, AggregationKey>() {... ...})
                                       .process(new ProcessAggregation(aggrDuration, statsdUrl))
                                       .map(new PassthruFunction(statsdUrl));  


public class ProcessAggregation extends ProcessFunction<JSONObject, JSONObject> {
    private ReducingState<JSONObject> recStore;

    public void processElement(JSONObject r, Context ctx, Collector<JSONObject> out) {
        recStore.add(r); //this line make the difference
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you are comparing against and what your use case is? `ReducingState` would certainly incur performance hits versus simply having a local variable and summing it up, but then you can't easily distribute that, checkpoint it, do it thread-safe, etc. Basically, all the reasons you'd use Flink :) So I think more it's not clear what your baseline is.

Comment: thanks @JoshuaDeWald, sounds like we shouldn't use ReducingState at all in Flink app :( I understand it will definitely impact performance but not expecting in that pattern. I believe aggregation not an uncommon case. So is this is an expected behavior? please share if it is not. Also adding the code for your reference. thanks.

Comment: If you will share the code (perhaps in a gist), I'll be happy to take a look. For the code shown here, I would not expect the performance to be this bursty.

Comment: Which state backend are you using? I know you said hdfs elsewhere, but that isn't the name of any of the Flink state backends. Is it the filesystem state backend, or rocksdb? And what type is recStore? It would also be helpful to see the whole lifecycle of the state -- are there timers, is the state being cleared, etc.

Comment: state.backend: filesystem
state.backend.fs.checkpointdir: hdfs://test.com:8020/flink/checkpoints
state.savepoints.dir: hdfs://test.com:8020/flink/savepoints

but the checkpoint is disable for this testing. Appreciated if you could advise.

Comment: @DavidAnderson checkpoint is disabled at the moment.

Comment: @DavidAnderson please use this instead https://github.com/swyow/flink_tester

Comment: you don configure this as flink arguement: "aggrinterval=3600000 loop=10000000 URL=test.com:8127". aggrinterval: aggregation interval in milisec, loop: number of record to test, URL: statsd server URL for monitoring

Comment: @user3771883 For these graphs you shared -- is this the JsonTranslator or the PassthruFunction?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, from JsonTranslator as we measuring the throughput.

Answer (score 1):

If your task can easily be done on a single machine with a small number of threads, then `flink` is likely overkill for you if the performance impact of doing the managed state is too much.

That said, you should not need to directly use `ReducingState` in this way, generally you would use the `aggregate` and `reduce` functions on Windowed operators (also, what's your window here?) It's not clear though when you are outputting your result. Are you continuously emitting the aggregate?

Is your source generating data that goes into multiple keys?

Are you using the default state backend or are you using RocksDB?

Additionally, You can look into using the convenience `sum` function that Flink provides, which will let you specify which fields to add against.

Comment: thanks. you are right that the performance impact is too much by using the state in single machine. But the test is perform with 4TM, each with 32 vCPU, and 100GB memory. In this case, process timer is used instead of window. Because window give us another performance issue, which the performance is capped and not scale-able. The source is generating data evenly to all TM with unique key(so merging is not happened in this test but every record will be stored as it own key just for throughout measurement). We are using filesystem backend now, so state is stored in TM memory.

Answer (score 1):

I've run a few experiments with the code you shared. I've only been running it on my laptop. I left all the statsd code in place, but I'm not running statsd. Instead I configured `web.refresh-interval` to 1 sec and observed `numRecordsOutPerSecond` in the Flink Web Dashboard. The only thing I changed was to modify the `GeneratorSource` to run continuously so I could observe the steady state behavior.

This is what I've seen:

1. Except while the job gets started, I am not seeing any dramatic fluctuations in throughput. There is an initial period of about 30 seconds during which the throughput steadily ramps up to a value that is then maintained quite consistently (after the initial startup phase it varies up and down by about 10%, with or without the `ReducingState`).
2. Updating the Flink version from 1.3.2 to 1.5.0 improved the overall throughput by nearly 2x. This isn't very surprising, as there's been a lot of work done on the Flink's network stack since 1.3.
3. Commenting out `mergedRecordStore.add(r);` also improves throughput by about 2x.

Looking at the code I see one thing that's causing some pain. You are doing your keying, serializing/deserializing, and reducing with JSONObjects. This is expensive. It would be better to convert the JSON into POJOs or Tuples, which will be cheaper to work with.

Comment: thank you David. Yes we discover the same at Flink GUI and the difference is the GUI will remain at previous value if no data between interval so you will not see the fluctuation. Thanks for information regarding to 1.5 improvement we will upgrade and see. May I know is it realistic if we expect linear performance gain by scaling TM?

Comment: You make a good point regarding the GUI, however, with 1.5.0 I'm pretty sure I was getting a value (nearly) every second (that was not the case with 1.3.2). As for scaling the TMs, yes, so long as the key space isn't skewed, this job should scale nicely.

Comment: it seems 1.5.0 has changes that would break existing application, for example REST API change. May I know if running 1.5.0 in legacy mode will enjoy the same performance benefit?

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not certain. I recommend you ask about that on the flink user mailing list.

Comment: Due to the bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-9500 we are not able to upgrade to 1.5. And even changing the class to POJO having the same issue. The performance drop because of fluctuation after adding reductionState. Do you think we should create a ticket?